# How can I fix this JQuery animation so it isn't choppy?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This JQuery animation looks very choppy, can I fix it? If not, how can I use CSS to do it? Maybe I use JQuery to edit the CSS?

```
<h1>Test</h1>

 <button onclick="anim()">Start Animation</button>

 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>


function anim() {
    $("h1").animate({fontSize: '50px'});
}

h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

[This is the example code](https://jsfiddle.net/z6ztfgcg/)

[Here's the project (you can also go to j0rdan.me)](https://github.com/j0rdancodes/j0rdancodes.github.io)

Comment: Choppy? It looks pretty fluid to me. But you could still use CSS3 transitions to make sure it's fluid, instead of JS transitions.

Comment: if you want to add more effects u can write a css class to perform animation and just add that class to <h1> on click.

Answer (score 3):

With CSS3 you can use transitions to animate the font-size:

```
h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
    transition: font 1s ease;
}
h1.bigger {
    font-size:50px;
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z6ztfgcg/3/

But to me it's not looking choppy with javascript from your example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css to add simple animations to your html:

```
.animClass {
    transition: 1000;
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

(Transition specifies the duration of animation in milliseconds)

Then just add the animClass when you need the animation to occur:

```
function anim(){ 
    document.getElementsByTagName("h1").classList.add("animClass");
}
```

Or in jQuery:

```
function anim(){
    $("h1").addClass("animClass");
}
```

I'm currently using my phone, so I wasn't able to check whether it works properly. Please inform me if further problems occur.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use only CSS then try this

```
h1 {
    -webkit-transition: all 1.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1.5s ease;
    transition: all 1.5s ease;
}

    h1:hover {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.5); /* Safari and Chrome */
        -moz-transform: scale(1.5); /* Firefox */
        -ms-transform: scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */
        -o-transform: scale(1.5); /* Opera */
        transform: scale(1.5);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few reasons why the animation is "choppy"

1. Animating structural properties such as `font-size` are generally choppy
2. Because the structure is changing, elements around the animated element will also be affected
3. jQuery animations aren't as smooth as css animations

I recommend animating with `css` not `jQuery` by using `transform: scale(1.5)` as this will not affect surrounding elements and gives a smoother animation.

```
h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
h1.larger {
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

If this is not possible and you want to animate the `font-size` I recommend setting the `line-height` to the size of the end animation size and having a fixed margin. This will hopefully prevent the surrounding elements from being affected.

```
h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
    line-height: 50px; // Matches end animation size
    margin: 20px 0;
}

h1.larger {
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

---

Working examples of both solutions:

https://jsfiddle.net/z6ztfgcg/4/

Answer (score 0):

Animating font-size will always be choppy because the transformation will skip keyframes. Best way would be to use CSS3 transition but with scale. This will ensure a smooth animation as you pretend.

```
<button onclick="anim()">Start Animation</button>
<h1 class="title">Test</h1>
<style>

    .title {
        position: absolute;
        transform: scale(1);
        transform-origin: 0 0;
        -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
        transition: all 5s;
        font-size: 30px;
    }
    .title.animate {
        transform: scale(2);
    }


</style>
<script>
    function anim() {
        $('h1').addClass('animate');
    }

</script>
```

You can then decide how many seconds you want the transition to be and change the scaling factor. (in this case I put 5 seconds and 2 times the original size)

Comment: you have to be aware though that with scaling an element having display: block; may overflow the width of the page.:)

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem that choppy on my end as well. You can try adding `transform: translateZ(0);` to the h1 CSS class: https://jsfiddle.net/z6ztfgcg/3/

This trick triggers GPU acceleration in modern desktop and mobile browsers, which should really smooth things out. There are plenty of other methods which accomplish similar tasks found [here](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/increase-your-sites-performance-with-hardware-accelerated-css).